# Independence of Coin Tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ represent the possible sequence of outcomes from tossing a coin twice.  It seems common to say, "Let $P(H) = p$, where $P(H)$ is the probability of getting a heads on either toss.  Then, since these are independent events, $P(HH) = p^2$."

However, the event $\{H\}$ is not measurable, so setting $P(H)$ is nonsense.  We also can't immediately say, "Getting a heads on the first toss and a heads on the second toss are independent," because we would need something like $P(H_1 \cap H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2)$, where $H_1, H_2$ are a heads on the first and second tosses, respectively.  But, again we don't such events.

It seems the rigorous way to go about this would be to first **assign** probabilities to events **in such a way that they end up being independent**, say, 
$$
P(HH) = p^2, \quad P(HT) = p(1-p), \quad P(TH) = (1-p)p,\quad P(TT) = (1-p)^2.
$$
Then, letting 
$$A = \{H \text{ on first toss}\} = \{HH, HT\}, \\
B = \{H \text{ on second toss}\} = \{HH, TH\},
$$
the event we are interested in is $\{HH\} = \{A \cap B\}$.  So,
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(\{HH\}) = p^2, \qquad P(A)P(B) = (p^2 + p(1-p))(p^2 + (1-p)p) = p^2,
$$
and indeed, getting a heads on the first toss is independent of getting a heads on the second toss.

I am just confused since we seem to be working backwards from "intuitive" probability.  Intuitively, I know what is *meant* by, "$P(H) = p$, and independence implies $P(HH) = p^2$," but once I lay it out rigorously this doesn't work.  Instead, it seems like we have to assign probabilities very carefully to the sequences of tosses so that the tosses **end up** being independent, rather than **assuming** they are independent from the beginning and start computing probabilities right away.  Have I overlooked something, or is my construction above really the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *do* have events $H_1$ and $H_2$, namely, they are the events
you labeled $A$ and $B$:
\begin{align}
H_1 & = \{ HH, HT \}, \\
H_2 & = \{ HH, TH \}. \\
\end{align}

In general, if $HH$, $HT$, $TH$, and $TT$ are simply the labels of events
in some arbitrary probability space $\Omega$,
these events might or might not be independent.
The sum of their probabilities merely needs to be $1$.

We do usually suppose, however, that a good model of two successive tosses
of the same coin would be a probability space for which
$P(H_1) = P(H_2)$ and for which $H_1$ and $H_2$ are independent.
The fact that $P(HH) = P(H_1 \cap H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2) = (P(H_1))^2$ follows immediately.
Let $P(H_1) = p$ as a more convenient way of writing $P(H_1)$,
and then $P(HH) = p^2$, $P(HT) = p(1-p)$, and so forth by simple algebra.

Comment: Basically, an event is a set of atomic outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking it.  It is natural to assume that flips of the same coin are independent events.  A coin seems too simple an item to have a memory.  That means we start from assuming there is a probability $P(H)=p$ which is independent of any history and proceed from there.  We use whatever data we collect to evaluate $p$

Comment: So, what does your sample space look like for two coin tosses, and is $\{H\}$ in its sigma algebra?  Of course what you wrote is what I've usually thought, but writing it out carefully, I see it's not this simple.

Answer (score 0):

$$
P(HH) = p^2, \quad P(HT) = p(1-p), \quad P(TH) = (1-p)p,\quad P(TT) = (1-p)^2.
$$

You have determined these probabilities by assuming independence, not designed them to make the events independent. Given the sample space $ S=H,T $ and defining $P(H)=p$ it is obvious that the alternative $P(T)=1-p$ by the axioms of a probability set function, but how do you know that $  P(HT)=p(1-p) $? What if getting a head changes the probability of getting a tail?  Independence is determined empirically beforehand.